React joyride multiple route skipping
I'm trying to make my React joyride accessible to multiple routes where we show the demo page, and then after the demo it returns back to the original page. However, it's good to have the first 3 steps that target the class/id, and then when the 4 steps come it jumps to the 0 or 10 part, which is on the main page. I want to target the demo route, but it's not working.
Tried applying the basic, controlled, custom component but didn't work.
jsx
const INITIAL_STEPS: Step[] = [
    {
        target: 'body',
        content: '0',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'center',
    },
    {
        target: '._container_olviv_1',
        content: '1',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'auto',

    },
    {
        target: '._container_olviv_1 ._box_olviv_18',
        content: '2',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'center',
        // spotlightClicks: true,

    },
    {
        // target: '._container_10dbq_65',
        target: '._container_zkz4b_69 > div ._day-list_zkz4b_111 ',
        content: '3',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        // spotlightClicks: true,
        placement: 'center'
    },


    {
        target: '._container_1owi2_1 > div:nth-of-type(1) button',
        content: '5',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        spotlightClicks: true,
        placement: 'auto'
    },

    {
        target: '._container_1n86c_1 ._upper-part_1n86c_28 ._status-badge_1n86c_65 > span',
        content: '6',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'bottom-end'
    },
    {
        target: '._container_1owi2_1 > div:nth-of-type(1) button',
        content: '7',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        spotlightClicks: true,
    },
    {
        target: '._container_1owi2_1 ul',
        content: '8',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'bottom'
    },
    {
        target: '._header_8qsd4_1 > div ._side-menu-container_8qsd4_73',
        content: '9',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        spotlightClicks: true,

    },
    {
        target: '._container_1tgjq_1',
        // target: '._container_1hztp_1 ._panel-container_1hztp_63._open_1hztp_75',
        content: '10',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'top-start'
    },
    {
        target: '._container_1hztp_1',
        content: '11',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        spotlightClicks: true,
    },
    {
        target: '._container_1hztp_1 ._panel_1hztp_63 > div > ul > li:nth-child(1)',
        content: '12',
        disableBeacon: true,
        placement: 'left-start',
        disableOverlayClose: true
    },
    {
        target: '._container_1hztp_1 ._panel_1hztp_63 > div > ul > li:nth-child(2)',
        content: 'These are frequently asked questions, and their answers.',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'right-start',
    },
    {
        target: '#support-slash-community-link',
        content: '13',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'right-start',
    },
    {
        target: '._accordion_u2i7m_1',
        content: '14',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'top-start',
    },
    {
        target: '._section_ssojg_1',
        content: '15',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        placement: 'center',
    },
    {
        target: "body",
        content: "16",
        placement: 'center',
        disableBeacon: true,
        disableOverlayClose: true,
        locale: {
            last: 'Close'
        }
    }
]

 const [showTourBtn, setShowTourBtn] = useState<boolean>(true)
    const [languageRun, setLanguageRun] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [tourRun, setTourRun] = useState<boolean>(false)

const steps = useMemo<Step[]>(() => {
        if (languageRun)
            return LANGUAGE_STEP

        return INITIAL_STEPS.map((step, i) => ({
            ...step,
            content: joyride_labels[i] || '',
        }))
    }, [languageRun, tourRun, joyride_labels])

const handleCallback = (data: CallBackProps) => {
        if (data.step.target === '#change-language-btn') {
            if (data.action === 'skip') {
                setLanguageRun(false)
                localStorage.setItem("nxt_joyride", "done")
                localStorage.setItem("nxt_joyride_language", user.email || 'none')
            }
        } else if (data.step.target === '#tour-btn') {
            if (data.lifecycle === 'complete') {
                setLanguageRun(false)
                localStorage.setItem("nxt_joyride", "done")
                localStorage.setItem("nxt_joyride_language", user.email || 'none')
            }
        }


        if (data.action !== 'skip') {
            navigate({ to: '/home' })
        }

        if (data.action !== 'next' && data.action !== 'update' && data.action !== 'prev')
            return

        const target = data.step.target as string

        if (data.index + 1 === 6) {
            navigate({ to: '/demo/quizzes' })
            return
        }

        if (target === 'body') {
            localStorage.setItem("nxt_joyride", "done")
            navigate({ to: '/home' })
        }


        if (!target.includes('demo-home')) {
            navigate({ to: '/demo/home' })
            return
        }

        // if (!target.includes("link"))
        //     return


        // // if (target.includes("archive-link")) {
        // //     navigate({ to: '/library/1'  })
        // //     return
        // // }

        // // if (target.includes("applied-studies-link")) {
        // //     navigate({ to: '/library/4'  })
        // //     return
        // // }

        const link = target
            .replaceAll("#", "/")
            .replaceAll(".", "/")
            .replaceAll("-slash-", "/")
            .replaceAll("-link", "")

        if (pathname.includes(link))
            return

        navigate({ to: link, params: undefined as never })

    }

